# Интересный глюк TeamViewer

Tags: teamviewer

Поможете разобраться?

Суть такая - с домашнего компа не цепляется на удалённый комп. Причем на удалённый комп не цепляется не только с моего, а ещё и с других разных (в том числе и провайдеры тоже разные) компов. Раньше всё подключалось нормально, никто ничего не менял (кроме, возможно, пришедшего обновления для TW), и вдруг враз перестало.
Но есть один интересный нюанс - на удалённый комп просто прекрасно подключается tw с телефона на android. И вроде бы он давненько не обновлялся => грешу на то, что может как-то протокол в последних версиях tw поменяли, там структуру пакета или ещё что. Ну либо не знаю - в чём (и есть ли) принципиальное отличие сети мобильной от сети такой, "обычной". IP-шник с мобильной сети тот же Новосибирский.
Может через сервера другие по мобильному подключается? К сожалению сейчас тел не рутованый, не могу поковырять сеть.

p.s. Никаких торрентов на удалёнке не стоит, файрволлы никакие не блочат. На шлюзе раньше никаких портов не было открыто конкретно для tw, и спокойно подключение происходило (шлюз на CentOS), после того, как подключаться перестало, пробовал и порты от tw в FORWARD скармливать и удалять, порой по-разному писалось, что то не может подключиться, то подключалось до разных стадий (но ни разу до просьбы ввести пароль), в итоге сейчас оставил 443 порт для защищённого соединения, и вот могу только с телефона подключиться. На удалённом компе teamviewer пишет, что готов к подключению, никаких слов ни о бане, ни о чем таком.

Что посоветуете, какие идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте на удаленном ПК временно рубануть selinux и iptables.

```
services iptables offnano /etc/selinux/config - там SELINUX=disabled
```

Сообщите результаты, будем дальше думать.

P.S. Еще вариант - несовпадение версий клиента teamviewer...

Comment: Извинясь за долгий ответ, selinux ещё сразу при установке вырубал, клиенты совпадают, НО... всё само восстановилось. Как я и предполагал, видимо какие-то работы были или глюки у самих TW на серверах, к которым tw с удалёнки коннектился, и видимо починили их, короче всё норм)